# Using MODI to OCR in C#. Need to read images from memory, not disk

Tags: c#, ms-office, ocr, modi

I'm trying to use MODI to perfom OCR on bitmaps I already have in memory. I can't seem to find a solution to this as all the examples I find use the create method to grab the image from the disk and prepares it for the OCR., however, I already have the image on memory and writing and reading i to and from the disk consumes too much time.

```
Bitmap bmp = ...
//Instantiate the MODI.Document object
MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();
//The Create method grabs the picture from disk snd prepares for OCR.          
md.Create("C:\\bmp.gif"); //but I don't want to read from disk :(
//Do the OCR.
md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, true, true);
//Get the first (and only image)
MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
//Get the layout.
MODI.Layout layout = image.Layout;
```

Comment: Dude, you need a spellchecker first.

Comment: This question was clearly hand-written, then converted by OCR.

Comment: I should've read it first before submitting. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  There is only one version of Create and it takes a file.
Make a temp file.  Save the image into it.  Delete the temp file.
Use Path.GetTempFileName() to do that.

```
string file = Path.GetTempFileName();
try {
    SaveImageToFile(image, file); // you decide how to best do this
    md.Create(file);
    // etc.
}
finally {
    File.Delete(file);
}
```

Comment: I know I can create a tmp file and do it, but that way is just too slow for what I'm trying to accomplish. I need to repeat this many times, so if that's the only way it sucks for me, I guess. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: Too bad.  You might also make sure that when you write a temp file (and you're going to have to), you use a file format that is fast to write and fast to parse.  This usually means TIFF or BMP with NO compression or PNG with NO compression and NO filters.  BMP with no compression is probably going to be fastest.

Comment: BTW, isn't GIF the best to use for this task ?

Comment: The time it takes to save an image to disk and have modi load the image usualy is usually insignificant when you compare it to the time it takes to actually do the OCR on the image.

Answer (score 0):

Can this MODI.Document Class read from a stream? Like the

`Image.FromStream(YourStream);`

That way you can create a memory stream and read from it.

Comment: I don't know. There's not much documentation for this MODI thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check MODI / OCR information on wikipedia

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Document_Imaging

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_character_recognition_software

Answer (score 0):

Simplest code to OCR an image using Microsoft Office's Imaging functionality (requires MS-Office 2007 or later, imaging components must be installed and MODI must be added to references).

```
private string OCR ( string fileToOCR)

{

MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();

md.Create(fileToOCR);

md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, true, true);

MODI.Image img = (MODI.Image) md.Images[0];

MODI.Layout layout = img.Layout;

layout = img.Layout;

string result = layout.Text;

md.Close (false);


return result; 

}
```

Calling function can be:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

MessageBox.Show ( OCR ("C:\\temp\\in.tif")); 

}
```